# How to graph log equation if given the following?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

So the question is
$$ Y= log(-x+2)$$
So I factored as my teach told the class that $x$ can only be subtracted
so I factored out
$$ Y = log(-(x-2))$$
[image]

Information I got from the following equation
$$ a = 1$$ $$h= 2$$ $$k = 0 $$
$h = 2$ cause of the factored
so this is how I thought I would graph
[image]
if what was written in the picture wasn't clear because of resolution

Anchor point of the equation because 2 was $h$ so it has to move 2 units from the original $(3,0)$ is the anchor point. When I checked the answer I found out that I did it wrong as even if it reflected over $y$ axis, it would cross the asymtote

How would i do this?

Answer (score 1):

No idea what's going on in the images but I'll go step by step as to how to graph the function.

1. As you already got, from this you know two things: the asymptote is equal to 2 AND the equation is reflected along the y-axis\begin{equation} y = \log (-x+2) = \log(-(x-2))\end{equation}
2. You find the anchor point by determining when y = 0, so \begin{equation} -x + 2 = 1 \end{equation}

   Therefore, x = 1.
3. So to conclude, the graph should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofnjJ.png

Comment: How did you get $$-x+2=1$$  I moved the anchor point (1,0), added the h and k and got (3,0)? is that not how you do it?

Comment: well, I don't know what you mean by "h" and "k", I've never used them before. What I'm doing is solving for the x-intercept. so y = 0. If log(1) = 0, then -x + 2 = 1